# Setting multiple paragraph styles in css

Tags: html, css

This is a top level question and is more based on my ignorance of css than anything else.  I am trying to create two paragraph styles in css, one with a 20px font size and another with a  14px font size.  However, no matter what I seem to do, the fonts come out the same.  Attached is an example of what I am doing right now, if anyone can point me to a solution I would great appreciate it. For brevities sake I am leaving out un-necessesary code.

the html code looks like this

```
<p>This is the html section with 20 px font</p>

<p class="new_font"> This is the html section with 8px font</p>
/* I have also tried this with a <div class="new_font"> and and <p id="new_font>"*/
```

the css code looks like this

```
p {
     /*text-indent: 1.5em;*/
     font: 20px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
     color: white;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 15px;
     text-align: justify;
     background: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.3); /* fallback color */
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
p new_font {
     /*text-indent: 1.5em;*/
     font: 14px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
     color: white;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 15px;
     text-align: justify;
     background: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.3); /* fallback color */
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: Just change `p new_font` to `p.new_font`

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/113/

Comment: Also no need to repeat all that css just change `font-size` https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/114/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're CSS is invalid, which is why it isn't applying:

```
p new_font {
   /* ... */
}
```

That should be written as

```
p.new_font {
   /* ... */
}
```

`p new_font` reads in English as "select all `new_font` tags that reside inside a `p` tag".

`p.new_font` reads in English as "select all `p` tags that have a class attribute set to `new_font`"

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/dh9av5jj/

You want to make `p new_font` into `p.new_font`.

`p new_font` says there is a paragraph with a new_font element inside it. new_font is not an element type.

`p .new_font` says there is a paragraph with an element inside it with the class new_font.

But you have new_font class on the paragraph so that selector is:

`p.new_font` which says I have a paragraph with the class new_font.

Answer (score 1):

Your simply missing the class dot declaration in your CSS.

If your referencing classes in CSS it's a `.` otherwise if your referencing a ID it's a `#`.

```
p {
    /*text-indent: 1.5em;*/
    font: 20px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.3); /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
p.new_font {
    /*text-indent: 1.5em;*/
    font: 14px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.3); /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```